# java.lang.nullpointer exception even if I instancied textview

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, textview

I have one textview with `visibility=gone`, and if some conditions are true, I want to set it to `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

This widget is inside a list_item layout which in turn inside listview.

Here is my Java code to set it to be visible:

```
if(sex_affiche && favori_affiche){
        mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this.getBaseContext(),
                listItem, R.layout.affichage_item_listview, new String[] {
                        "nom", "tel","sex","favori" }, new int[] { R.id.item_nom,
                        R.id.item_tel, R.id.item_sex_jdida, R.id.item_favori });

        listedescontacts.setAdapter(mSchedule);
        registerForContextMenu(listedescontacts);

        if(sex == null){
            Log.d("null", "yes");
            TextView sex2  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_sex_jdida);
            if(sex2 == null)
            Log.d("still null", "yes");
            else
                sex2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        //favori.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

I have instanciated it in `oncreate` and I redo in this method but it's always null.

Comment: Check your current Activity XML is having TextView with **"@+id/item_sex_jdida"** id or not?

Comment: yes I have, if not, I will have a error

Comment: @begiPass you have it in `R.layout.affichage_item_listview` not in your activity layout so you get NPE

Comment: please look where exactly the nullpointer is. A lot of (beginning) developers talk about exceptions but they have no clue that your logging **exactly tells you what line of code it is in**. my guess is maybe listedescontacts is null

Comment: all works fine, for now I don't have the exception because I check it it is null, and otherwise I have an exception in sex2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textview that you're trying to access is in the list; so you can't have a direct access to them. What you could do is to override `getView()` from adapter and inside it get the view and make it visible (**blind coding**):

```
    mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this.getBaseContext(),
            listItem, R.layout.affichage_item_listview, new String[] {
        "nom", "tel","sex","favori" }, new int[] { R.id.item_nom,
        R.id.item_tel, R.id.item_sex_jdida, R.id.item_favori) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View superView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView sex2  = (TextView)superView.findViewById(R.id.item_sex_jdida);
            if(some_condition) {
                sex2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                sex2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return superView;
        }
    };
```